# Selecting parent node of non-excluded paths based on excluded paths

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have the following in an sql table:

```
path
------
/
/a
/a/a
/a/b
/a/b/c
/b
```

I will be marking at least one path as excluded and then perform a "Select a list of non-excluded parent nodes" query.

The desired output for various scenarios are as follows:

```
Scenario  Excluded Path(s)  Desired Output  Remarks
1         /a                /b              because /a/a, /a/b, /a/b/c are children of /a

2         /b                /a

3         /a/b              /a              because /a/a is not excluded
                            /b

4         /a/a              /b              because /a/b/c is the only child of /a/b
          /a/b/c                            and /a/a and /a/b are children of /a
```

Answer (score 1):

So to state it more completely:

```
For a given path P, find top-level nodes 
having any children not on path P
```

However, the third and fourth desired results do not appear to follow this rule, so either it is too late and I should not be answering this, or the rule is not clearly defined.

Anyway, doing this in SQL is tricky using strings, but I will assume they are all one letter and separated by slashes.

```
select left(path,1) as topNode
  from theTable
 where path not like '/x/y%'
 group by left(path,1)
```

If they are not one letter, which I assume they are not, we have to examine how they are stored in the table.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, your proble has little relation with "nodes" and "paths". You are simply looking for strings (paths) that do NOT begin with the specified prefix. 
If that is so, the problem is simple, look [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html).